# Using local variables from "child" functions

Tags: bash, variables, scope

Consider following code:

```
function child()
{
    echo $var
}

function parent()
{
    local var=5
    child
}
```

I've tested it on my machine and it seems to work but I wasn't able to find anything definitive describing such usage of local variables. Namely, when I declare a local variable in one function and from that function I call some other function, can I use the variable in the latter (and even nest it deeper)? Is it legal in bash and is it standard for all versions?

Comment: From man bash `When local is used within a function, it causes the variable name to have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children.`

Comment: Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: From man sh `The shell uses dynamic scoping, so that if the variable x is made
     local to function f, which then calls function g, references to the
     variable x made inside g will refer to the variable x declared inside f,
     not to the global variable named x.`

Comment: Can't be bothered writing a full answer soz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` uses dynamic scoping. The value of `var` in `child` is not determined by where `child` is defined, but by where it is *called*. If there is no local definition in the body of `child`, the next place the shell looks is in the body of the function from which `child` is called, and so forth. The `local` modifier creates a variable in a function that is local to that call, so it does not affect the value of the variable from any enclosing scopes. It is, though, visible to any *enclosed* scope.

```
a () { echo "$var"; }
b () { local var="local value"; a; }

var="global value"
a  # outputs "global value"
b  # outputs "local value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just complimenting what user 123 already mentioned in the comments

From bash man pages

> Variables local to the function may be declared with the local builtin command.  Ordinarily, variables and their values  are  shared  between
>          the function and its caller.

```
bash3.2.25->cat function.ss 
#!/bin/bash
function child()
{
        echo "child function called"
        echo $var
}


function parent_global()
{
        echo "parent_global called, child invoked outside parent"
        var=5
}

function parent()
{
        echo "parent called, child invoked inside parent"
        local var=5
        child
}

parent
parent_global
child
bash3.2.25->./function.ss 
parent called, child invoked inside parent
child function called
5
parent_global called, child invoked outside parent
child function called
5
```

So unless specified otherwise (the *local* builtin), variables are visible outside the function scope, global if you will.